# Thread information logging

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to write these thread information into a log - like thread number/name, date time started etc.

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    threads[i] = new Thread(() =>
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
        ActualMethod(); //Goes here...
        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("path of the file", true)) 
        {
            //Write to a text file...
        }

    });
    threads[i].Start();
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    threads[i].Join();
}
```

If i try to add code to write to a file inside the thread code(ie. line after ActualMethod(), i get cross-thread exception - variables can't be accessed outside the thread.

Comment: Removing the excessive indentation before posting (most text editors can tab/untab) is a "nice" thing to do.

Comment: This is why you use a logging framework rather than just writing stuff to a file willy nilly.

Comment: Are you sure that "path of the file" is some explicit string value, not something like `TextControl21.Text` (or same for "Write to a text file.." portion)?

Comment: @KirkWoll - While indeed logging frameworks are useful, it probably will not fix the problem. I believe exception has nothing to do with code shown here, but rather related to code that is hidden inside comments. Creating writers is fine on any thread...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - The path of the file is a private string variable holding the file path. I am trying to send these threads[0].ManagedThreadId information inside the thread and getting cross-thread exception.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 so use simply Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId inside thread body, you do not need to access threads[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log file in your code is a shared resource used without any synchronization. So there are at least two problems if you want to use the same file for all threads:

1. With code:

   ```
   using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Projects\StackOverflow\log.txt", true))
   ```

   your are opening file exclusively because `StreamWriter` implementation open this file with `FileAccess.Write` access and `FileShare.Read` share mode:

   ```
   new FileStream(path, mode, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.SequentialScan, Path.GetFileName(path), false, false, checkHost);
   ```

   Other threads (each after the first one) can't open it in the same mode again.
2. Even if threads would open this file, without any synchronization, they can be race conditions in file access.